# Create SQL assertion that count() from one table is less than a tuple value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, assertion

There is are two tables:

Classes(**CourseNo, SectionNo, Year, Semester**, Capacity) (bold indicates a key).

Enrollments(**CourseNo, Year, Semester, SectionNo, StudentNo**, Grade)

How would I use SQL in order to ensure that the number of enrollments in each class is less than that classes capacity?

I know how to do the parts individually, but the comparison between the count() of students enrolled in each class and the capacity of that class is where I get lost. I don't know how to make sure it compares to the right value.

Thanks

EDIT: I am using SQL Server 2008 to create this assertion, but I would like to know how to do it regular SQL, in addition to creating a trigger in SQL Server (as it does not support assertions)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using that supports `CREATE ASSERTION`?  Please tag your question with the database technology you're using.  It would help folks give you the best answer for the database you're using.

Comment: I have updated the tags as well as added in some more context :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.CourseNo, c.SectionNo, c.[Year], c.Semester, Capacity, count(*) as Enrolled
from classes as c 
 join enrollments as e
  on c.CourseNo = e.CourseNo
   and c.SectionNo = e.SectionNo
   and c.[Year] = e.[Year]
   and c.Semester = e.Semester
 group by c.CourseNo, c.SectionNo, c.[Year], c.Semester, Capacity
 having count(StudentNo) > Capacity
```

Comment: With `and c.SectionNo = e.SectionNo
   and c.[Year] = e.[Year]
   and c.Semester = e.Semester` I only certain class sections. If I join them on only courseno, then it seems that i get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select courseno, capacity, count(*) as enrollments
from classes c 
join enrollments e on e.courseno = c.courseno
group by c.courseno , capacity
```

Comment: This seems to work as it returns what I need. However, when I attempt to apply the condition of "Capacity > Enrollments", I get the error:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Enrollments'.`

This is using:

`Where Capacity > Enrollments.`

I have also tried using the having clause, but it still does not give me the desired result.

Comment: Upon further inspection, this code doesn't work properly. The count(*) is calculating the number of students enrolled in each course, but not by section. Each course can have multiple sections, and the capacity represents each specific section.